# failed get data to android project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My project is showing cryptocurrency price application
So i want get current_price

this is my firebase structure

[image: data structure]

this is my Coin.class and then it include getter/setter method in class

not describe in this code

```
public class Coin {
public String acc_trade_value;
public String acc_trade_value_24H;
public String closing_price;
public String current_price;
public String fluctate_24H;
public String fluctate_rate_24H;
public String max_price;
public String min_price;
public String opening_price;
public String prev_closing_price;
public String units_traded;
public String units_traded_24H;

public Coin(){

}

public Coin(String acc_trade_value,String acc_trade_value_24H,
            String closing_price,String current_price,String fluctate_24H,
            String fluctate_rate_24H,
            String max_price, String min_price, String opening_price,
            String prev_closing_price, String units_traded, String units_traded_24H)
{
    this.acc_trade_value = acc_trade_value;
    this.acc_trade_value_24H =acc_trade_value_24H;
    this.closing_price =closing_price;
    this.current_price = current_price;
    this.fluctate_24H = fluctate_24H;
    this.fluctate_rate_24H = fluctate_rate_24H;
    this.max_price =max_price;
    this.min_price = min_price;
    this.opening_price = opening_price;
    this.prev_closing_price = prev_closing_price;
    this.units_traded = units_traded;
    this.units_traded_24H = units_traded_24H;
}
}
```

Running this code
Error -> ClassMapper: No setter/field for -MXwJ8urI_wf4P8c8k2v found on class

how did I fix it?

+) get data code

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Bithumb/"+data.getText());
    DatabaseReference Coin = mDatabase;
    Coin.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot :snapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Coin coin = snapshot.getValue(Coin.class);
                System.out.println(coin);
                String current_price = coin.getCurrent_price();
                holder.market_price.setText(current_price);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Please edit your question to also include the code that reads from the database. That's most likely where the mistake is.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  I edit my post, I want to save the current price to market_price using setText.

Comment: what does `data.getText()` contain?

Comment: @Zein data.getText() is getter method for get trade code like 'ADA' ,'BTC' etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Bithumb/"+data.getText());
DatabaseReference Coin = mDatabase;
Coin.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot :snapshot.getChildren())
        {
           // replace snapshot -> dataSnapshot
            Coin coin = dataSnapshot.getValue(Coin.class);

            System.out.println(coin);
            String current_price = coin.getCurrent_price();
            holder.market_price.setText(current_price);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

Just replace snapshot with dataSnapshot in you code, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

just do a small change in the model class, by adding a `String key` and getter + setter of it. then follow the code below and making all the variables as private;

**The updated model class below:**

```
public class Coin {
    private String key;
    private  String acc_trade_value;
    private String acc_trade_value_24H;
    private String closing_price;
    private String current_price;
    private String fluctate_24H;
    private  String fluctate_rate_24H;
    private  String max_price;
    private  String min_price;
    private  String opening_price;
    private String prev_closing_price;
    private  String units_traded;
    private  String units_traded_24H;


    public String getAcc_trade_value() {
        return acc_trade_value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public void setAcc_trade_value(String acc_trade_value) {
        this.acc_trade_value = acc_trade_value;
    }

    public String getAcc_trade_value_24H() {
        return acc_trade_value_24H;
    }

    public void setAcc_trade_value_24H(String acc_trade_value_24H) {
        this.acc_trade_value_24H = acc_trade_value_24H;
    }

    public String getClosing_price() {
        return closing_price;
    }

    public void setClosing_price(String closing_price) {
        this.closing_price = closing_price;
    }

    public String getCurrent_price() {
        return current_price;
    }

    public void setCurrent_price(String current_price) {
        this.current_price = current_price;
    }

    public String getFluctate_24H() {
        return fluctate_24H;
    }

    public void setFluctate_24H(String fluctate_24H) {
        this.fluctate_24H = fluctate_24H;
    }

    public String getFluctate_rate_24H() {
        return fluctate_rate_24H;
    }

    public void setFluctate_rate_24H(String fluctate_rate_24H) {
        this.fluctate_rate_24H = fluctate_rate_24H;
    }

    public String getMax_price() {
        return max_price;
    }

    public void setMax_price(String max_price) {
        this.max_price = max_price;
    }

    public String getMin_price() {
        return min_price;
    }

    public void setMin_price(String min_price) {
        this.min_price = min_price;
    }

    public String getOpening_price() {
        return opening_price;
    }

    public void setOpening_price(String opening_price) {
        this.opening_price = opening_price;
    }

    public String getPrev_closing_price() {
        return prev_closing_price;
    }

    public void setPrev_closing_price(String prev_closing_price) {
        this.prev_closing_price = prev_closing_price;
    }

    public String getUnits_traded() {
        return units_traded;
    }

    public void setUnits_traded(String units_traded) {
        this.units_traded = units_traded;
    }

    public String getUnits_traded_24H() {
        return units_traded_24H;
    }

    public void setUnits_traded_24H(String units_traded_24H) {
        this.units_traded_24H = units_traded_24H;
    }
}
```

**Now use the code below to retrieve data from firebase:**

```
  mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Bithumb").child(data.getText());
    DatabaseReference Coin = mDatabase;
List<Coin> coinList = new ArrayList<>();
    Coin.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot :snapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Coin coin = snapshot.getValue(Coin.class);
                coin.setKey(snapshot.getKey());
               
                coinList.add(coin);
                
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: if it works then kindly mark it as the correct answer.